# How can I sort a clojure set of maps?

Tags: clojure

I have a set of maps something like this:

```
#{
  {:name "a" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
  {:name "b" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
  {:name "b" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
  {:name "a" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
  {:name "c" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
  {:name "a" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
}
```

: and I want to get to an ordered list, much like sql order-by name:

```
[
  {:name "a" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
  {:name "a" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
  {:name "a" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
  {:name "b" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
  {:name "b" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
  {:name "c" :value "b" ... more stuff here}
]
```

: how can I do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Function [sort-by](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/sort-by) is what you're looking for:

```
(def s
  #{
    {:name "d" :value "b" }
    {:name "b" :value "b" }
    {:name "c" :value "b" }
    })
(sort-by :name s)
```

Comment: Simple, precise, concise. Worked like a charm @Leonel

Answer (score 7):

sort-by is a great answer, and makes the code a lot better in the simple cases where it works. Additionally the sort function can take a function to extract the comparason key from each map incase you need to do some processing on each item. In this example i use a sort function that extracts each name and then does a string compare on them.

```
(sort #(compare (:name %1) (:name %2)) data)
=>  ({:name "a", :value "b"} {:name "b", :value "b"} {:name "c", :value "b"})
```

this is useful if your collections had different names to be compared:

```
(sort #(compare (:value %1) (:name %2)) data)
=> ({:name "a", :value "b"} {:name "c", :value "b"} {:name "b", :value "b"})
```

the `compare` function is a better version of java's .compareto() because it properly handles nil and compares clojure collections properly. is is basically a short cut for using the . opperator in most cases

```
(sort #(. (:name %1) (compareTo (:name %2))) data)
=> ({:name "a", :value "b"} {:name "b", :value "b"} {:name "c", :value "b"})
```

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain a bit more please how this would work?

Answer (score 5):

`(def set-of-maps #{{:name "d"}, {:name "b"}, {:name "a"}})`

-> [clojure.core/sort-by](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/sort-by)

`(sort-by :name set-of-maps)`

`; => ({:name "a", :value "b"} {:name "c", :value "b"} {:name "d", :value "b"})`

Answer (score 4):

`sort-by` is what you want, but please post snippets that are actually valid code; I wasted a fair bit of time trying to figure out a problem that wound up being because `#{{:name "a" :value "b"} {:name "a" :value "b"}}` makes the reader barf.

Comment: the "more stuff here" would have prevented the duplicate key error.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the snippet from the joy of clojure is the neatest.

```
(def plays [{:band "Burial",     :plays 979,  :loved 9}
           {:band "Eno",        :plays 2333, :loved 15}
           {:band "Bill Evans", :plays 979,  :loved 9}
           {:band "Magma",      :plays 2665, :loved 31}])

(def sort-by-loved-ratio (partial sort-by #(/ (:plays %) (:loved %))))
```